# Can't create a list that involves another function

Tags: python

I have a board (named tab) that is a tuple with three tuples that contain 3 values (1, -1 or 0). My code contains 9 values (1 tuple * 3 tuples * 3 values each small tuple) and the function eh_posicao_livre identifies if a certain position in tab is "0" (and if so it returns True) or "1" & "-1" (if so it returns False). My last function called getting_free_position compiles in a list (called lista) the positions that in tab the number is "0" (my code is huge cause I'm new but you can ignore the eh_posicao_livre cause it's right). The problem is in the last function that it doesn't work and I don't know why. I'll leave the expected result at the end

```
tab = ((-1,1,0),(1,0,-1),(0,-1,1))
    
def eh_posicao_livre(tab, pos):
    if pos == 1:
        if tab[0][0] == 0:
            return True
        elif tab[0][0] == -1 or tab[0][0] == 1:
            return False
        else:
            raise ValueError('eh_posicao_livre: algum dos argumentos e invalido')
    elif pos == 2:
        if tab[0][1] == 0:
            return True
        elif tab[0][1] == -1 or tab[0][1] == 1:
            return False
        else:
            raise ValueError('eh_posicao_livre: algum dos argumentos e invalido')
    elif pos == 3:
        if tab[0][2] == 0:
            return True
        elif tab[0][2] == -1 or tab[0][2] == 1:
            return False
        else:
            raise ValueError('eh_posicao_livre: algum dos argumentos e invalido')
    elif pos == 4:
        if tab[1][0] == 0:
            return True
        elif tab[1][0] == -1 or tab[1][0] == 1:
            return False
        else:
            raise ValueError('eh_posicao_livre: algum dos argumentos e invalido')
    elif pos == 5:
        if tab[1][1] == 0:
            return True
        elif tab[1][1] == -1 or tab[1][1] == 1:
            return False
        else:
            raise ValueError('eh_posicao_livre: algum dos argumentos e invalido')
    elif pos == 6:
        if tab[1][2] == 0:
            return True
        elif tab[1][2] == -1 or tab[1][2] == 1:
            return False
        else:
            raise ValueError('eh_posicao_livre: algum dos argumentos e invalido')
    elif pos == 7:
        if tab[2][0] == 0:
            return True
        elif tab[2][0] == -1 or tab[2][0] == 1:
            return False
        else:
            raise ValueError('eh_posicao_livre: algum dos argumentos e invalido')
    elif pos == 8:
        if tab[2][1] == 0:
            return True
        elif tab[2][1] == -1 or tab[2][1] == 1:
            return False
        else:
            raise ValueError('eh_posicao_livre: algum dos argumentos e invalido')
    elif pos == 9:
        if tab[2][2] == 0:
            return True
        elif tab[2][2] == -1 or tab[2][2] == 1:
            return False
        else:
            raise ValueError('eh_posicao_livre: algum dos argumentos e invalido')
    else:
        raise ValueError('eh_posicao_livre: algum dos argumentos e invalido')


def getting_free_position(tab):
    pos = 1
    lista = ()
    while pos < 10:
        for eh_posicoes_livres(tab, pos):
            if True:
                number = pos
            lista += (number,)
            pos += 1
        return lista

getting_free_position(tab)
```

This is the result that I want to get --> (3,5,7)
Thanks in advance guys!!

Comment: 1. Don't write code in your native language, it makes it hard to understand for everyone. You wouldn't like me asking you a question about code in Cyrillic.
2. Did you mean to write `if eh_posicoes_livres(tab, pos):` instead of `for eh_posicoes_livres(tab, pos): if True`?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that the code didn't really matter in what language it was as long as it is said what every function does. I think that's correct, but even if I put "if" it still doesn't work. I'll try to translate this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for loop is used to iterate over sequence, so `for eh_posicoes_livres(tab, pos):` which result in `for True` or `for False` is wrong. You should use `if eh_posicao_livre(tab, pos):` as Nikola comment. (Please note that you misspelled the function name, you use `eh_posicoes_livres` in the last function not `eh_posicao_livre` you defined.)

Although you say the result is put in a list (e.g. [3, 5, 7] surrounded by square brackets), your expected result is surrounded by round brackets which is a tuple. Therefore, I assume you want a tuple instead of a list.

```
tab = ((-1,1,0),(1,0,-1),(0,-1,1))

def getting_free_position(tab):
    pos = 1
    lista = ()
    while pos < 10:
        if eh_posicao_livre(tab, pos):
            number = pos
            lista += (number,)
        pos += 1
    return lista

print(getting_free_position(tab))
```

Output:

```
(3, 5, 7)
```

---

#### Suggestion:

In fact , you can just loop through the tab to get the result without defining the first function:

```
tab = ((-1,1,0),(1,0,-1),(0,-1,1))

def get_pos(tab):
    pos = 1
    result = ()
    for t in tab:
        for v in t:
            if v == 0:
                result += (pos,)
            pos += 1
    return result

print(get_pos(tab))
```

If you still want a function to check a certain position, you can flatten the tuple first.

```
tab = ((-1,1,0),(1,0,-1),(0,-1,1))

def isfree(tab,pos):
    # flat_tab = (-1, 1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1)
    flat_tab = tuple(v for t in tab for v in t)
    if 0 <= pos - 1 < len(flat_tab):
        return flat_tab[pos-1] == 0
    # may add else statement to return some value or raise error when pos out of index

print(isfree(tab,3)) # Output: True
print(isfree(tab,6)) # Output: False
print(isfree(tab,9)) # Output: False
print(isfree(tab,-1)) # Output: None
print(isfree(tab,10)) # Output: None
```